# how check bitcoind default values

Tags: bitcoind

How can I see which values bitcoind is using for eg. dbcache, or other memory and connection params ? If the value is NOT set in bitcoin.conf. Is there a bitcoin-cli command to check all the params ?

Answer (score 1):

You can see all available command options by running the command `bitcoind -?`. 
Similarly, in the GUI you can check out "HELP" -> "Command Line Options" in the task bar.

This will return a list of all available commands, as well as their default values (when applicable). Note that this just returns *all possible command options*, not specifics about what you have set. Default values will be used unless you specify otherwise, and I believe the hierarchy for specifying a command option is:

`An option passed on command line when starting bitcoind 
(takes precedence over)
an option passed in .conf file 
(takes precedence over)
an option set in the GUI`

(Information pulled from [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Command-line_arguments))

Comment: I don't see any option for dbcache (for instance), how can a find out the default value?

Comment: No? Which version are you running? With v0.17.01 I see it under the *Options* section at the top: `-dbcache=<n> ... default: 450`

Comment: you are right, I was looking at bitcoin-cli instead of bitcoind